# Need to iterate multiple attribute values along with each other

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, javascript-controller

I have Multiple attributes in my component and need each to iterate along with each other. I can only iterate each attribute values separately as of now.

```
 Component
===========
<aura:component  access="global" controller ="ChatterFeedController">
<!--Attribute-->
<aura:attribute name = "groupattid" type="String" /> 
<aura:attribute name = "groupatt" type="String[]" /> 
<aura:attribute name = "actorphoto" type="String[]"  /> 
<aura:attribute name = "actorName" type="String[]"  /> 
<aura:attribute name = "attachPreview" type="String"  />   
<aura:attribute name = "attachment" type="String[]" /> 
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.userFeedItem}" value="{!this}"/>

 // Something like this
<div class ="slds">
 <aura:iteration>
 {!v.actorphoto}
 {!v.actorName}
  <br/>
 {!v.groupatt}
 {!v.attachment}
 </aura:iteration>
</div>
 </aura:component>


       Controller
      ============
  ({

userFeedItem: function(component, event, helper) {
    var userFeed = component.get("c.getFeedData");
    var groupID = component.get("v.groupattid");
     console.log("GroupID: " + groupID);
    userFeed.setParams({"groupId" : groupID});
    userFeed.setCallback(this,function(response){
    var state = response.getState();
        if(state==="SUCCESS"){
           var jtext      = response.getReturnValue();
           var groupatt   = component.get("v.groupatt");
           var actorName  = component.get("v.actorName");
           var actorPhoto = component.get("v.actorphoto");
           var attach     = component.get("v.attachment");
           var attachpreview = component.get("v.attachPreview");
    for (var i=0; i<jtext.elements.length; ++i){ 
        var actor = jtext.elements[i].actor;
        var body = jtext.elements[i].body;
        var item = jtext.elements[i].capabilities; 
          if(body && body.messageSegments.length){ 
                 groupatt.push(body.text);
               actorName.push(actor.name);
               actorPhoto.push(actor.photo.smallPhotoUrl);

          }
      component.set("v.groupatt",groupatt);
      component.set("v.actorName",actorName);
      component.set("v.attachment",attach);
      component.set("v.actorphoto",actorPhoto);
      console.log("attach"+attach);
    }

 } else {
            console.log('Problem getting feed, response state: ' + state);
        }    
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(userFeed);
}
```

Comment: I can see from your controller that `groupatt`, `actorName`, `actorPhoto` will have same number of items. Can you confirm that the other attribute `attachment` will also have same number of items?

Comment: Seems to me this begs for a different approach.....maybe...

Comment: Hello @SantanuHalder. No . Attachments may or may not be present. So it does not mean the number of items and attachment is same.  But that is something that I have anticipated earlier and just added here to be changed later. My concern is only with the other attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be not possible with the current approach.

You can change your approach slightly to this:

**1.** Instead of segregating the individual values from the jText.element, you can keep it like the way it is. I am guessing its a list of wrapper class instances, let's say the wrapper class name is: `PersonInfo`.

**2.** Declare a single attribute instead of 3 or 4 different lists.

```
<aura:attribute name = "personList" type="PersonInfo[]" />
```

**3.** Improvise your setCallback to this:

```
userFeed.setCallback(this,function(response){
  var personListLocal = component.get('v.personList');
  var state = response.getState();
  if(state==="SUCCESS"){
    var jtext= response.getReturnValue();
    for (var i=0; i<jtext.elements.length; ++i){ 
      personListLocal.push(jtext.elements[i]);
    }
    component.set('v.personList', personListLocal);
  }
}
```

**4.** Then loop through the personList in your component and access its values.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.personList}" var="person">
  {!person.actor}, {!person.body.text}, {!person.capabilities}
</aura:iteration>
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks @Santanu It worked perfectly.. One more thing.. The feed body I am getting is not properly displayed in the UI in proper format. It comes as a single string which is understandable as I am passing it to an attribute of String[] type. So instead of coming like this:

        < This is just for a test.
         1. Paragraph 1
         2. Paragraph 2
         3. Paragraph 3  >

it is coming like this:

<This is just for a test. 1. Paragraph 1 2. Paragraph 2 3. Paragraph 3>.

Is there any way to display it in proper format as which it was written?